# No image file after make (3.6 kernel compiling)

Tags: cross-compilation, kernel

**Overview:** I wanted to compile 3.6.11+ linux kernel for my raspberry, after the `make` command, there were no image files in arch/arm/boot.

---

What I've done:

1 Download the linux code from `github.com/raspberrypi/linux` and cross-compile tools from `github.com/raspberrypi/tools`, all in zip format.

2 Extract and deploy them like this:

`export KERNEL_SRC = /home/loon/Downloads/linux-rpi-3.6.y/

export CCPREFIX = /home/loon/Downloads/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi-`

3 Do clean work before:
`loon@ubuntu:~/Downloads/linux-rpi-3.6.y$ make mrproper`

4 Copy the config file from current Raspberry system: (from /proc/)
`zcat config.gz > ~/Downloads/linux-rpi-3.6.y/.config`

5 Then make it:
`loon@ubuntu:~/Downloads/linux-rpi-3.6.y$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CCPREFIX}`

6 The making process ends like these:

`CC [M]  drivers/usb/serial/zio.o

LD [M]  drivers/usb/serial/usbserial.o

  LD      drivers/usb/built-in.o

  LD      drivers/built-in.o

loon@ubuntu:~/Downloads/linux-rpi-3.6.y$ cd arch/arm/boot/`

Shouldn't there be `zImage` or `Image` in `arch/arm/boot`? But all I found are:
`loon@ubuntu:~/Downloads/linux-rpi-3.6.y/arch/arm/boot$ ls

bootp  compressed  dts  install.sh  Makefile`

---

This problem has been solved by myself. Answer is simple:
use `git clone` instead of downloading zip archive file from Github.

I finally find that the internal file structure is corrupted when the big ZIP archive has been extracted, maybe some missing of symbol links or else.

Compilation using source code from `git clone` will get the desired Image and zImage in `arch/arm/boot`

Comment: Welcome to raspberry pi stackechange, could you please explain what you have done here? what is the question? or did you have a question and found the answer yourself?

Comment: @kolin - Sorry that I've made my first question kind of difficult to read, I'll edit it now.

Comment: Im having this same issue, for the love of GOD PLEASE HELP ME!!! I've spent a total of 20 hours, yea not joking, trying to get this to work. And your explanation is a tad vague. Im using this (For MAC)
http://elinux.org/RPi_Kernel_Compilation
Any help on what git clone means? Where Do I put it?